# Store value of a cell when it is entered

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript code for creating a row of a table:

```
function create_row() {
    var table = document.getElementById("main_table");
    var n = table.rows.length;
    var m = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(n);
    for (i=2; i<m; i++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        cell.innerHTML = "<input size=4>";
        cell.addEventListener("change", function () {
            console.log("Column of a cell: " + cell.cellIndex);
        })
    }
}
document.getElementById('create_row').onclick = create_row;
```

My intention is that when a user types something in the cell, I want to print that value. However, `cellIndex` is always the number of columns in my table (or `m`) (as I understand, because the cell is clicked after all cells are created, and thus `i` reached `m`).

How can I receive row, column, and the value of a cell when the content of it was changed?

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: I was about to post this as an answer, but it got duped while I was checking it. When you generate each cell, you can give it a custom attribute combination - i.e. `<td row="3" column="4"></td>` Then in your `change` listener, make the function pass that value back, like this:
`cell.addEventListener("change", function () {
        console.log("Row " + this.getAttribute('row') + " Column " + this.getAttribute('column'));
        // call the function with those values as arguments
    })`

Here's an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/opf16x7y/

Answer (score 1):

Oooh, Javascript closures. Try this:

```
function create_row() {
  var table = document.getElementById("main_table");
  var n = table.rows.length;
  var m = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(n);
  for (i=2; i<m; i++) {
    create_cell(i);
  }
}

function create_cell(){
  var cell = row.insertCell(i);
  cell.innerHTML = "<input size=4>";
  cell.addEventListener("change", function () {
    console.log("Column of a cell: " + cell.cellIndex);
  })
}

document.getElementById('create_row').onclick = create_row;
```